# JavaScript - How to dynamically add to a nested object array

Tags: javascript, templates, facebook-messenger-bot

I am trying to make a messenger bot that can create buttons based on a number I enter. The code looks like this:

```
let messageData = {
    "attachment": {
        "type": "template",
        "payload": {
            "template_type": "button",
            "text": text[1],
            "buttons":[]
        }
    }
}
```

The part that says "buttons":[] is where I want to add buttons (inside the []) according to this format:

```
{
   "type":"postback",
   "title":"button" + i //where i is the button number,
   "payload":"button" + i
}
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: messageData.attachment.payload.buttons.push(obj) where obj is the JSON.

Comment: Sorry if this sound "noobish", but how would I create the JSON?

Comment: Nvm, I got it. Your solution worked, thank you so much!!

Comment: written an explanation that you should probably read so you get a better understanding of what JSON are. (basically dictionaries in any other language).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your example you can do this:

```
messageData.attachment.payload.buttons.push(obj)
```

the `.` accesses the object's key, which can also be done this way `messageData['attachment']` 
The difference between

```
messageData.attachment
```

and

```
messageData['attachment']
```

is that the second one can take a variable instead of a string, e.g.

```
var use_key = 'attachment';
messageData[use_key];
```

will access the same as the other two above.

JSON is just short for `JavaScript Object Notation`. And you make it exactly like your second example:

```
{
   "type":"postback",
   "title":"button" + i //where i is the button number,
   "payload":"button" + i
}
```

You can assign it to a variable to pass it into the push, or just exactly as it is. Not much different from a string or number. Don't let all the extra information scare you.